# --exclude-lang = "xml" is not working using cloc

Tags: cloc

I have used --exclude-lang = "xml" and --exclude-lang = "designer.cs" to exclude designer and xml files from count of lines changes in two different folders but it's not working.

Answer (score 5):

Simple case of mis-capitalization.  An easy way to troubleshoot this issue is to run `cloc .`

In your console, you'll see a table report printed like this:

[image: cloc . output]

You posted that you used: `--exclude-lang = "xml"`.  Instead you need to match the language description exactly.  In the consoles output, you can see `xml` is all caps.  If you update your flag too `--exclude-lang="XML"` you'll see that XML scanning is ignored.

Answer (score 2):

Several languages can be excluded for instance by:

```
--exclude-lang="SVG,CSV,XML,Markdown,TeX,reStrcuturedText"
```